# Probability formula

Tags: probability

I am struggling a bit with following problem.

You are given $P(A \cup B)= 0.7 $ and $P(A \cup B^c)= 0.9 $.

Determine $P(A)$.
I know the answer is $0.6$.

Honestly, I cannot figure out how to get to this one.

Any help would be appreciated.
Regards,

Comment: Have you tried to draw a Venn diagram of the situation?

Comment: Honestly, I did not because I do not master them enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given the following known relationships:
$$
\begin{align}
&P(A \cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B)\\
&P(A) + P(A^c) = 1\\
&P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c) = P(A)
\end{align}
$$
we can do the following:
$$
\begin{align}
&P(A) + P(B) - P(A \cap B) = 0.7\\
&P(A) + P(B^c) - P(A \cap B^c) = 0.9\\
&2P(A) + \left(P(B) + P(B^c)\right) - \left(P(A \cap B) + P(A \cap B^c)\right) = 0.9+0.7 = 1.6\\
&2P(A) + 1 - P(A) = 1.6\\
&P(A) = 0.6
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Brilliant Avraham. Many thanks.